# After Installing Kivio I am not able to open it?

Tags: 15.04

I need a program to create some flow charts. I have found that a really good option is Kivio, so I have downloaded and installed it, but I am not able to open it. I thought that after installation a launcher was going to be created, but it wasn't.

So, can somebody who had experienced this issue help me?

By the way, I am using Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Open the terminal and try running `kivio` . If that works, we can find out where the binary is and create a `.desktop` shortcut for it

Comment: I have done that and I get Sorry, there is nothing that matches your search.

Comment: Hmmm, how about `ls /usr/bin | grep -i kivio` ? anything ?

Comment: I have run that in the terminal and I have gotten nothing again.

Comment: By the way, I looked up kivio, but it's the former name. It's now part of Calligra office suite and is called Calligra Flow . You might wanna try searching for that

Comment: How did you install it by the way ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is part of Calligra Office, I have that installed. I installed it using the file on this link:  [Kivio](http://kivio.en.uptodown.com/ubuntu)

Comment: @Serg. Thank you so much. If you want you can add your answer and I can accept it as valid.

Comment: Wait , you found it ?

Comment: Yes,  I have typed Calligra Flow and I open the this program. I am exploring this I like it so far, so this solved my problem.

Comment: OK, then. I guess I'll post an answer. Though I though you only installed kivio by itself.

Comment: I thought the same that I had just installed Kivio. Calligra Office is not installed. Calligra Flow is what has been installed instead of Kivio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Kivio` is the former name of this application. It's part of Calligra office suite and is called `Calligra Flow`, so you may want to search for that instead.